# How to disable 'button focus' in several buttons in PyGTK?

Tags: python, button, pygtk, pygobject

I'd would like disable the *focus* in all the buttons of my window. I can disable one button with `widget.set_can_focus(False)` but I'd like to know the canonical way to apply this feature to all buttons in my window.

FYI, I am using `HBox` and `VBox` containers.

Comment: Are you sure you want `set_can_focus`?  To disable a button, I use `set_sensitive`.

Comment: No, I disable the 'focus' in the button. Not the button. @Mark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would iterate through a list of the buttons and then use "duck typing" to disable their focus.

For example:

```
button_widgets = [button1, button2, ..., buttonN]

for button in button_widgets:
    button.set_can_focus(False)
```

UPDATE:

how to loop through all elements in a HBox or VBox to find buttons:

If you have the name of the HBoxes or VBoxes at the lowest layers containing the buttons you can simply loop through them, check for buttons and then add them to a list. Here's an example in which I print out all buttons in an HBox:

```
import gtk
import pygtk
hbox = gtk.HBox()
button1 = gtk.Button('1')
button2 = gtk.Button('2')
hbox.add(button1)
hbox.add(button2)
for i in hbox:
    if type(i) == gtk.Button: print i
```

Outputs:

```
<gtk.Button object at 0x1909320 (GtkButton at 0x171e8e0)>
<gtk.Button object at 0x19093c0 (GtkButton at 0x171e9a0)>
```

Comment: Do you know a way to list all buttons in the Window? I mean a PyGTK function.